# Probability Mass Function and interpretation of question

Tags: probability, self-study

QN1).
A person has n number of fruits, however only one of them is fresh. If the fruits are randomly chosen, and if it is stale, the fruit will be thrown away.

Qn 1) What is the probability mass function of X, when X is the number of tries to get the fresh fruit?

Qn 2) 
If the fruit isn't thrown away, what will happen to the probability mass function of Qn 1?

p.m.f : p(x) = P(X=x)

p(x) = P(X=?)

I am unsure of how to start this question at all...

QN2).
A, B and C are independent variables. What is the probability that A and either B or C takes place? The question means P (A and (B or C)).

Can I simplify the question to P(An(BuC))?
I am not sure if 'either B or C' can be interpreted as P(BuC).

Comment: Hi. It's my first time using this website, so I didn't know how to use it. Thank you for telling me that. However, you are mistaken regarding me trying to get answer for free. I just don't know how to start this question at all...

Comment: "I am unsure of how to start this question at all..." Start by calculating P(X=1), P(X=2).